# How can I get present months?

Tags: java, android-studio

I tried

```java
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("use with command get time \"calendar.getTime()\"           : "+calendar.getTime());
System.out.println("use with command get month \"calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)\": "+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

but I can't get the right month.

[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9k4g.png)

How can I get the current month? Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You could just add 1 to whatever `get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns, because it returns a number from 0 to 11.  But seriously?  If someone is teaching you how to use the `Calendar` class, you should probably choose a new teacher.  That class has been obsolete for about 10 years.

Comment: tks. and sorry for my lack of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

## `java.time.LocalDate`

You can use below to get month value in int or string

```
LocalDate.now().getMonthValue();
LocalDate.now().getMonth();
```

Comment: tks ^^, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `SimpleDateFormat` method to get the current date and time.

Here see in my function I get the current date and time for your reference

```
private void getTime(TextView dateTime) {
    Date date = new Date();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa");
    dateTime.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
}
```

For more information, you can refer to the [official android documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples from official documentation. [Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#examples)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
Date date = new Date();
Log.d("MyTag", sdf.format(date));
```

Here `MM` represents months in integer form (dec ~ 12)
Here `MMM` represents months in alphabets (Dec)

Comment: These terribly flawed classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: tks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Sriram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957856/642706) is correct, and provides the modern solution using [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. Here are a few more details.

## Time zone

The `LocalDate#now` method implicitly uses the JVM’s current default time zone. Time zone is critical because for any given moment the time, and therefore the date, can vary around the globe by zone. It can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously be “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you omit passing the `ZoneId` object, the JVM‘S current default time zone is automatically applied. This has the same effect as explicitly passing the default.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
```

I recommend the explicit approach to make your intentions crystal-clear.

## `Month` enum

The method [`LocalDate#getMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonth()) returns a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum object.

```
Month month = LocalDate.now().getMonth() ;
```

If you want to generate text to represent that value, you can automatically localize.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
String output = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/vP6BPa).

> décembre

You can access the JVM’s current default locale by calling `Locale.getDefault()`.

## Android

Android 26+ carries an implementation of the *java.time* classes.

For earlier Android, use the latest tooling to access most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for class `java.util.Calendar`, you will find the following constant:

```java
    /**
     * Value of the {@link #MONTH} field indicating the
     * twelfth month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars.
     */
    public static final int DECEMBER = 11;
```

Hence `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))` correctly returns 11 (eleven).

However, Android 8 (API level 26) added class [LocalDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate) which should be used instead of class `Calendar`. Note that class `Calendar` contains both date and time whereas class `LocalDate` contains the date only. Class `LocalDateTime` contains both a date and a time. There is also class `LocalTime`.

According to the documentation for [static] method `now`, in class `LocalDate`:

> Obtains the current date from the system clock in the default time-zone.

If you want the current month, you can call method `getMonthValue` which...

> Gets the month-of-year field from 1 to 12.

Alternatively, you can call method `getMonth` which...

> Gets the month-of-year field using the `Month` enum.

So your code should be:

```java
java.time.LocalDate calendar = java.time.LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("calendar           : " + calendar);
System.out.println("calendar.getMonth(): " + calendar.getMonth());
```

which produces the following output:

```
calendar           : 2022-12-30
calendar.getMonth(): DECEMBER
```

Comment: tks for your help ^^

Comment: @NguyễnAnhViệt you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer or up-voting it (or both).